# Possible to create a more efficient homing missile system in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've written a homing missile script for my action platformer and I cant help but notice that this might not be the most efficient of weapons.

```
void Start()
    {
        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy");
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        direction = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        rotatetoTarget = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotatetoTarget, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x * fowrardSpeed, direction.y * fowrardSpeed);
    }
```

It works perfectly but there are a few issues with it. How do I ask it to randomly select a different enemy every time it is instantiated? Rather than all going for one enemy?

Also once that enemy has died, it should choose a new target, but wont performing `GameObject.Find()` in `Update()` be a bad thing? I understand that `GameObject.Find()` is to be avoided as it goes over all of the gameObjects in the scene until it finds what it is looking for, and if need be should only be used in `Start()`. Now I had to use `GameObject.Find()` when the weapon instantiates as I could not find of any other way to locate the target for the weapon. So is there a better way to chose a new target once that target is destroyed? My game is a game where reaction time matters and I dont want to create any unnecessary lag due to this weapon

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have an `EnemyCache` and `MissileSpawner` script.

Your `EnemyCache` (most likely a singleton) would have a list of enemies in the world;
Enemies are added into that list when they are spawned, and removed from that list when they die.

Your `MissileSpawner` (or something that spawns the projectiles) script would then need to assign the missiles a target each time it spawns a new missile.
It can fetch a target for the new missile via the `EnemyCache`. (You can even filter the list to get the closest target too!)

Finally, your missile script can fetch a new target from the `EnemyCache` if the old target died.

Overall, it should look *similar* to this:

#### YourMissile.cs

```
public class YourMissile : MonoBehaviour {
    // ...

    GameObject target;

    public void Update() {
        // target is destroyed or gone
        if (target == null) {
            SetTargetFromEnemyCache();
        }
    }

    private void SetTargetFromEnemyCache() {
        if (EnemyCache.Instance.TryGetFirstEnemy(out Enemy newTarget)) {
            target = newTarget.gameObject;
        } else {
            Debug.LogWarning("No enemy for missile to target!");
        }
    }

    // ...

    public void SetTarget(GameObject targetToSet) {
        target = targetToSet;
    }

    // ...
}
```

#### EnemyCache.cs

```
public class EnemyCache : MonoBehaviour {
    // Singleton
    public static EnemyCache Instance { get; private set; }

    private List<Enemy> cachedEnemies;

    private void Awake() {
        Instance = this;
        cachedEnemies = new List<Enemy>();
        // TODO: Subscribe to a delegate or event, that adds into the 'cachedEnemy' whenever an enemies spawned.
        // Also, an event that removes from 'cachedEnemy' when an enemy dies too.
    }

    // ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to fetch the first enemy in the cache.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enemy">The fetched enemy; Null if there was nothing in cache</param>
    /// <returns>True if there is an enemy fetched; False if none</returns>
    public bool TryGetFirstEnemy(out Enemy enemy) {
        if (cachedEnemies.Count > 0) {
            enemy = cachedEnemies[0];
            return true;
        }
        enemy = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### YourMissileSpawner.cs

```
public class YourMissileSpawner : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    private YourMissile missilePrefab;

    // ...

    public void SpawnProjectile() {
        YourMissile newMissile = Instantiate(missilePrefab);

        // Set position... etc...

        // Try to get a target for the new missile
        if (EnemyCache.Instance.TryGetFirstEnemy(out Enemy enemyToTarget)) {
            newMissile.SetTarget(enemyToTarget.gameObject);
        } else {
            Debug.LogWarning("No enemy for newly spawned missile to target!");
        }

        // NOTE: The above is optional,
        // since 'YourMissile' sets a new target from EnemyCache
        // if the target is null; (checks per update)

        // But I included it here in case you want it to filter
        // what kind of enemy it needs to target on start :)
    }
}
```